# Расположение файла hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, log4j2

Проект Maven с использованием Hibernate. При запуске возникают ошибки:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default   configuration: logging only errors to the console.
 Failed to create sessionFactory  object.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not  locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.art.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
at com.art.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:16)
... 5 more
```

Что это за файл log4j2?Зачем он?Почему он вызывает ошибки?

Файл hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        root
    </property>

    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="com/art/Employee.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка `Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]`. Вот в ней проблема, а не в конфигах логера.

Comment: @Vartlok, добавил hibernate.cfg.xml, что в нем не так?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, он лежит кто-то не там.

Comment: @Vartlok, а где он должен лежать?

Comment: обычно `src/main/resources` http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736719/1646082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: файл должен находится в `src/main/resources`.

Подробное объяснение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736719/1646082

Comment: Может быть, переведёте ответ целиком на русский? Просто ссылки недостаточно для хорошего ответа. :)